# PHP 5.4.4-9 (debian testing) - require_once not pulling files recursively

Tags: php

I'm getting sort of an unexpected behaviour while trying to implement a class A that uses a class B. Here are the contents of the files:

```
> cat test.php
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once("A.php");
//require_once("B.php"); //now it'd work, but it's not the point

$a = new A();
$b = $a->getB();
var_dump($b);
$b->sayHi();
> cat A.php
<?php

require_once('B.php');

class A
{
        private $b;

        public function getB()
        {
                return $this->b;
        }

        public function __construct()
        {
                $b = new B();
        }
}
> cat B.php
<?php

class B
{
        public function sayHi()
        {
                echo "Hi!";
        }
}
> php test.php
NULL
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function sayHi() on a non-object in /var/www/przypadek_testowy/test.php on line 10
```

Is there some PHP quirk I should have known about? Requiring B.php in test.php is ugly in this case and I'd prefer a better solution.

Comment: `$b = new B();` you mean `$this->b` right?

Comment: As commented, the problem is with your code. Regardless, using `require` for classes is ugly no matter where you use it. If possible, switch to autoloading: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Thanks for answers! It was definitely worth the minus points I got for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$b = new B();` with: `$this->b = new B();` in your `A` class.

See also that [`require_once`](http://php.net/require_once) is a statement, not a function. So you can use it without quotes.

Comment: `private class vars name should begin with and underscore` this is php4 style, since php 5 you have access modifiers, so no need to prefix it. In fact underscoring properties should not be used, as of https://github.com/pmjones/fig-standards/blob/psr-1-style-guide/proposed/PSR-2-advanced.md#42-properties

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! Fixed my answer. Sorry